# JavaScriptSerializer: Cannot deserialize JSON that uses @ symbol in property name

Tags: c#, .net, javascriptserializer

I am using a 3rd party server that exposes an API via REST(so it is not possible to change the JSON). The JSON it returns is in a format like:

```
    [
         {
              "@noun":"tag",
              "@version":0,
              "@tag":"myFoo"
         }
    ]
```

I created a C# object to represent this item

```
    public class ResponseItem
    {
        public string noun {get;set;}
        .....
    }
```

however, when I try to use the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize this object, the properties do NOT get assigned. The serializer seems to be unable to handle the properties with the @ symbol in front of the name.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You say you can't change the source of the JSON, but could you filter the JSON text prior to deserializing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after some finagling, I ditched the JavaScriptSerializer. I switched over to the DataContractJsonSerializer. I then use well defined data contracts and use the DataMember attribute to specify the name.

i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseItem
{
    [DataMember(Name="@noun")]
    public string Noun {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

There may be a better/different way, but this works and is an acceptable solution